# Joining tables laravel and keeping first table ids

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I noticed that when you join tables in laravel using lefJoin() or Join the ids that it returns are the one of the last table. So I was wondering if I can join two tables in laravel and keepig the ids of the first table?

Here's my query

```
$comments = DB::table('posts')
->where('posts.parent_id',$id)
->leftJoin('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')   
->get();
```

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: Here it is posted it

Comment: Ran across something similar this morning, just constrain the columns it returns, like `->select("posts.*")`, and if you need variables from the other tables, add `profiles.whatever`, just don't use `profiles.*` or `users.*`.

Comment: But that's not going to join all 3 table isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

you should show ur code . 
but try like this

```
$query = Users::where("users.user_id","=",$users->user_id)
               if ($request->exists('product_name')) {
                $query->join('products', 'users.user_id', 'products.user_id');
                $query->where('products.product_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('product_name')
                . '%');
            }

            $test= $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use aliases in this case.For Example

DB::table('table_1')->select('table1.column_name as alias_name', 'table_2.column_name as alias_name2')->leftjoin('table_2', 'table_2.userId', '=', 'table_1.id')
->get();

Comment: But it returns only the columns selected with their alias

Comment: You need to specify all columns you want to return in query.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all from first table and nothing from second

`DB::table('table_1')->join('table_2', 'table_1.id', '=', 'table_2.table_1_id')
   ->selectRaw('table_1.*')
   ->get();`

Example `DB::table('guests')->join('answers', 'guests.id', '=', 'answers.guest_id')
  ->selectRaw('guests.*')->get()`

You also can select here anything from another table

use: `->addSelect('table_2.column')`

Comment: When I use select raw it returns only the table selected, and when I use addSelect it returns only the column selected

Comment: use it togheder write slectRaw first to select all columns from first table, then write addSelect to select any column from another table

Comment: DB::table('table_1')->join('table_2', 'table_1.id', '=', 'table_2.table_1_id')
   ->selectRaw('table_1.*')->addSelect(table_2.column)
   ->get();

Comment: if you want to select more than 1 column from the second table you can try to pass an array to addSelect method, or write as much addSelect as you need

Comment: DB::table('table_1')->join('table_2', 'table_1.id', '=', 'table_2.table_1_id') ->selectRaw('table_1.*')->addSelect('table_2.column') ->addSelect('table_2.column2')->get();

Comment: or ->addSelect(['table_2.column', 'table_2.column2'])

Comment: If you do not understand smth you can open a chat i'll explain